# How do I manually schedule multi-thread tasks in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

Recently, I want to achieve a multi-thread task scheduler. More precisely, I have multiple machine learning jobs but only a few CPU cores. Thus, I want to write a scheduler to distribute the computational resources to those tasks. However, when I directly use a thread pool, it is impossible to control the opportunity of suspension and neither impossible to distribute the computational resources. I know my requirements might be similar to coroutines. However, my tasks are CPU-intensive rather than IO-intensive. So how can I manually control the suspension and resumption of multi-thread tasks?

Comment: Python seems have no multi-thread but multi-proccess. Your question might be something about IPC(inter proccess communication.

Comment: In fact, there exists some ambiguity in my question. As per my current requirements, I only need to leverage one-core and just let those tasks share the resources. Therefore, it doesn't matter that there exists a GIL in Python.

Comment: What does the resources you want your tasks shared include you mentioned? file?memory? cpu?

Comment: I want to share the CPU time. The reason for this is that I need to conduct several numerical optimization tasks simultaneously. However, my total computational time is limited to 8 hours. Thus, I intend to allocate CPU time to those tasks.

Comment: I think you want to let multi-core to do the same work, not to share the cpu time among tasks in one core.If the task framework do not support do the work use multi-core, you need to implement the multi-work yourself by using multi-process, while multi-thread in python only run in one process with one core.